# Binding and Updating LINQ object in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, gridview

I'm totally having trouble with a Gridview that's been stumping me all day.  I don't use Gridviews very often so some of this is confusing me and Google hasn't been as much help as I was hoping.

I'm trying to bind an object created through LINQ to a gridview and then do some updating.

XAML:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GV1"
        onrowediting="gridViewUsers_RowEditing"
        onrowcancelingedit="gridViewUsers_RowCancelingEdit"
        onrowdeleting="gridViewUsers_RowDeleting"
        onrowupdating="gridViewUsers_RowUpdating"
        >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    List<Room> stuff = new List<Room>();
    Hotel = dc1.Rooms.ToList();

    GV1.DataSource = Hotel;
    GV1.DataBind();
}

protected void gridViewUsers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GV1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    BindGrid();
}
```

I want to just grab the Room object from the selected row and update it back to the database through LINQ.  But I can't seem to get my hands on that object.  My next attempt was to grab each entry from the row.  So I found code like the example below.  But everything is null.

```
    protected void gridViewUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        string tenant = ((TextBox)(GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Tenant"))).Text;
        string age = ((TextBox)(GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Age"))).Text;
        string roomno = ((TextBox)(GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Room_No"))).Text;            
        BindGrid();
    }
```

Comment: I think it's just a typo , but your `gridview` ID is `GV1` while in updating event it's `gridViewUsers_RowUpdating` so are you sure you are accessing correct gridview for your fields??

Comment: That is a typo.  The method name was taken from another GridView I had found.  It is pointing to the right method and I am tracing into that method.

Comment: If you have not defined column explicitly then as `Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets` posted define your columns and then you can easily access your control using `Textbox txtbxtenant = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant");`

Comment: I did change the gridview to explicitly define columns.  I'm sorry I can't give you the example because I'm now at work and away from the code.  But Textbox txtbxtenant = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant"); still pulled back null when I tried it last.

Comment: The closest I've come so far is ((TextBox)GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text pulls back the original value.  I can't find the edited value.  GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Controls.Count is 1 so there aren't any other controls in the cell.

Comment: No that means you have a single control in one cell as you have defined different columns for tenant , room etc . So Cell numbering starts from `0` so to access roomno change cell no accordingly.

Comment: Well that's fine if I'm just reading the existing records.  But how do I get ahold of the edited fields?  That's kinda the point of the "Update" method.

Comment: You should be getting edited values in your updating event, Well check the code where you are binding your `gridview` in page_load event and put your binding method inside `(!Page.IsPostBack)`

Comment: what i think is when your page does postback your code binds gridview again and you get old values , So use `!Is.PagePostBack`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41273/discussion-between-suraj-singh-and-jeremy)

Comment: I think you might be right.  I've been in CMS land for so long, I forgot about little quirky things like PostBack.  I'll try it when I get home tonight.  I'll let you know.  Thank you Suraj.

Comment: Your welcome :) . Ciao !

Answer (score 0):

Try to set AutoGenerateColumns = false and provide columns manually.
Something like:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GV1"
    onrowediting="gridViewUsers_RowEditing"
    onrowcancelingedit="gridViewUsers_RowCancelingEdit"
    onrowdeleting="gridViewUsers_RowDeleting"
    onrowupdating="gridViewUsers_RowUpdating"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false"
    >
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowEditButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Tenant" DataField="Tenant" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Age" DataField="Age" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Room_No" DataField="Room_No" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

EDIT:
Please add this code to your solution

```
public static int GetCellIndexByFieldHandle(this GridView grid, string fieldHandle)
{
    int iCellIndex = -1;

    for (int iColIndex = 0; iColIndex < grid.Columns.Count; iColIndex++)
    {
        if (grid.Columns[iColIndex] is DataControlField)
        {
            DataControlField col = (DataControlField)grid.Columns[iColIndex];
            if ((col is BoundField && string.Compare(((BoundField)col).DataField, fieldHandle, true) == 0)
                || string.Compare(col.SortExpression, fieldHandle, true) == 0
                || col.HeaderText.Contains(fieldHandle))
            {
                iCellIndex = iColIndex;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return iCellIndex;
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the ordinal index of a TableCell in a rendered GridViewRow, using a text fieldHandle (e.g. the corresponding column's DataFieldName/SortExpression/HeaderText)
/// </summary>
public static int GetCellIndexByFieldHandle(this GridViewRow row, string fieldHandle)
{
    return GetCellIndexByFieldHandle((GridView)row.Parent.Parent, fieldHandle);
}
```

And try

```
string tenant = ((TextBox)GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].GetCellIndexByFieldHandle("Tenant")].Controls[0]).Text;
```

Comment: I did that and still got null when I tried to .FindControl().

Comment: Is there no way to just grab the selected Room?

Comment: Well there was an error because neither of the extension methods had only one argument.  So I changed the call to .GetCellIndexByFieldHandle(GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex], "Tenant")] however, I get an error "Extension Method must be defined in a non-generic static class".  There's gotta be an easier way of doing this.

Comment: Yes should move extension methods to some static class.

Comment: I guess if your are creating column statically through markup you can use cell indexer to find correct cell. Cell[1] for example.

Comment: The example above worked to find the original value but not to find the changed value as I'm editing the row.

Comment: However I'm still having a lot of trouble believing you need to go through all of this just to get the value out of a cell.  It's almost easier to use a table and populate/update data manually than jump through all these hoops.  It doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to access your `textbox` values .

```
 protected void gridViewUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
         GridViewRow row = gridViewUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        Textbox txtbxtenant = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant");
         string tenanat = Convert.toString(tentant.text);
        Textbox txtbxAge =(Textbox)row.FindControl("Age");                   
        string age = Convert.toString(Age.text);
       // string roomno = ((TextBox)  
       //(GV1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("Room_No"))).Text;            
       // BindGrid();

    }
```

Comment: tenant and Age are null.  So tenanat and age throw "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: @Jeremy Please check the updated answer, If that doesn't works let me know .

Comment: (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant"); still returns null regardless of what you call the textbox you put it in.  :(

Comment: @Jeremy It's not about renaming  `textbox` i referred to `Convert.Tostring` i added when assigning textbox value to string. However can you please post your gridview code ?

Comment: I'm confused.  Textbox txtbxtenant = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant");
string tenanat = Convert.toString(tentant.text); so you're converting a string that you are currently creating to a string?  That's going to break.

Comment: And doing Convert.ToString(txtboxtenant.Text) will also error because it is null.

Comment: @Jeremy what is null? If you are talking about `textbox` value then `Convert.ToString` will handle `Null` values or if you are saying that You are unable to get control or `FindControl` method is failing , then please post your code .

Comment: Your Textbox txtbxtenant = (TextBox)row.FindControl("Tenant"); line returns null even though there is a field called "Tenant".  Any field I try to find using row.FindControl always returns null.

Comment: What are you missing that's not in the OP?  I don't have that gridview in front of me.  The only difference between what I'm currently trying and what's in the OP might be the suggestion Yevgeniy made to turn off autogenerate columns and explicitly define the columns.

Comment: @Jeremy See if you are creating `columns` dynamically, then you have to access them using cell number, this is your responsibility to let others know ,that's why i was asking for your gridview code.